# how to include an environment variable in the launcher?

Tags: launcher, environment

I was trying to make some scripts dynamic by including the environment variable $LOGNAME and even $HOME. but it don't seem to work when placed in a launcher.

I am trying to make code a bit more dynamic

```
/home/simon/Desktop/firefox_test.bash
```

I tried

```
$HOME/Desktop/firefox_test.bash
```

and

```
/home/$LOGNAME/Desktop/firefox_test.html
```

but it don't seem to read the environment variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starter commands usually aren't evaluated by a shell so environment variable don't get evaluated.

Use

```
 sh -c '$HOME/Desktop/firefox_test.bash'
```

or

```
 sh -c 'xdg-open /home/$LOGNAME/Desktop/firefox_test.html'
```

Comment: haha.. that did it. @FlorianDiesch thanks for the answer