# How to include environment Variable in launcher for icon

Tags: gnome, launcher, environment-variables

This is an extension to the question [how to include an environment variable in the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139195/how-to-include-an-environment-variable-in-the-launcher) . This question explains how to use the environment variable for the `Exec` part of the `.desktop` file but not the icon

an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Application name
Comment=a comment
Exec=sh -c '$HOME/.bin/path/to/bin'
Icon= $HOME/.bin/path/to/icon
```

This Launcher will work but the icon is not shown. I can't use something like

```
Icon=sh -c '$HOME/.bin/path/to/icon'
```

for the icon... what to do instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly the best way to use an icon in a launcher is to make sure the icon file is in the icon search path. Referring to the [freedesktop.org icon directory scheme](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#directory_layout) and [base directory definitions](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), icons should be searched for in at least the following directories on Ubuntu systems:

- `$HOME/.icons`
- `$HOME/.local/share/icons`
- `/usr/local/share/icons`
- `/usr/share/icons`
- `/usr/share/pixmaps`

So if you want to use your own icon and do not have root privileges, install the icon into either `$HOME/.icons` or `$HOME/.local/share/icons`. Using the latter, you can even mimic the system icon directory structure with multi-resolution icons using the same base name under directories like `$HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps` and `$HOME/.local/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps`.

If the icon is in one of these searchable directories, you can simply use `Icon=myapp` in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: `Icon=myapp` does not work for me, I need to provide the full path (`Icon=/usr/share/icons/myapp.png`). Does the icon need to be named `myapp.png`, and I need to omit the extension in the \*.desktop file? Or does the icon need to be in a subdirectory named `myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyApp
Exec=sh -c "mv %k %k-bak && sed -e "s,^Icon=.*,Icon=$HOME/.bin/path/to/icon.png,g" %k-bak > %k && chmod +x %k; rm %k-bak"
Icon=???
```

This will add the relative Icon path to the .desktop file after you run it.

Some more details:

`%k`stands for the path of the .desktop file

1. `mv %k %k-bak` creates a backup file
2. `sed -e "s,^Icon=.*,Icon=$HOME/.bin/path/to/icon.png,g" ...` replace the old Icon path with the current $HOME... path ("^" -> beginning line, is here really importand to not replace the command self) and create the new .desktop file
3. `chmod +x %k` make the new .desktop file executable
4. `rm %k-bak` remove the old backup file

You can add your own commands after the Icon path was changed or before.

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/3464561 and https://askubuntu.com/a/345123/265974

Comment: i don't have root access, so I can't use `/usr/share....` and I want to sync the starter between different computers, which is why I need a more generic soluteion with `$HOME` or something like this...

Comment: @Jonas i've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks! Yes that might work...but isn't there any easier solution? Why does gnome shell not evaluate environment variables?

Comment: Sorry i dont't know.