# What's wrong with this .desktop file?

Tags: .desktop

I can't figure out what's wrong with this. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand), it should work. Thanks!

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=D3GO
Comment=D3GO televizija preko interneta
Exec=~/D3GO/D3GO
Path=~/D3GO/
Icon=~/D3GO/D3GO.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: What if you replace `~` by the actual path names?

Comment: Hmmm. I understand, but this is .desktop file which should be on multiple computers, not just mine. How to replace it with the user who runs installation script which will copy this file?

Comment: Use actual pathnames and place the file you need to execute in /opt/

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
Exec=~/D3GO/D3GO
Path=~/D3GO/
Icon=~/D3GO/D3GO.png
```

You must to use the [full path names](https://askubuntu.com/q/337443/147044).

Comment: There are some tricks to use relative paths... [how to include an environment variable in the launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139195/how-to-include-an-environment-variable-in-the-launcher) and [How to include environment Variable in launcher for icon](http://askubuntu.com/questions/476233/how-to-include-environment-variable-in-launcher-for-icon)