# .Desktop EXEC universal home path

Tags: home-directory, .desktop

I am making .desktop for teamspeak as their programmers didn't.

It ought to work for everyone and to do so I need to target home folder universaly with EXEC.

So let's pretend program X is in `~/.local`

- `/home/username/.local/X` this way works only for me

EDIT: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139195/how-to-include-an-environment-variable-in-the-launcher/139198#139198) solved it for EXEC but doesn't apply to the ICON thus I placed it to `/usr/share/icons` which is **workaround**.

Comment: why did you accept an answer that does not even *possibly* work?? Relative paths like `$HOME` do not work in a `.desktop` file.

Comment: " That's not enough. See askubuntu.com/a/139198/158442 – muru Feb 19 at 19:37 " as you can see it was posted *before* you did comment here and I have had also *already* included in my EDIT.. so congratulations for writing before reading.

Comment: I mentioned you accepted an answer *before* the edit was made on the answer (an edit after my comments on the answer). You should accept an *answer*, not including a comment in your own question. As said, you accepted a non working answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `HOME`. It stores the absolute path to the current user's home folder.

Here's how you can use it:

```
Exec=/bin/sh -c "$HOME/.local/X"
```

It's **very** important putting the `$` before `HOME` so it's read as a variable. Also do not forget write `HOME` in capital letters only.

Don't forget to wrap shell variable using `"` double quote else it will fail at execution time.

Comment: That's not enough. See http://askubuntu.com/a/139198/158442

Comment: @EduardoCola I'd appreciate if you don't take it as-, -nor make it- a personal thing. When using `sh -c` or `/bin/bash -c` anything can be done, since either  `sh` or `bash` is running the command then. When using your construction directly in the `Exec=` line, it simply doesn't *possibly* work, and the answer is a non- working one. You shouldn't want that. Accepted or not.

Comment: `plasmashell` expands `~` in `Exec` just fine, no need for `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Just checked: it does not expand `~` in `Exec`, but it does expand `$HOME` (without `sh -c ...`)

Comment: @Shevchuk Your experience is different from mine. I invoke my `*.desktop` files with `Exec=~/...` on daily basis and `plasmashell` executes them without fail. My login shell is `/bin/bash`. You may like to verify your checks.

Comment: @Shevchuk Post a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you need help.