# Need a Universal Username for a .desktop file. Can someone help? $USER / $LOGNAME Don't Work. 18.04

Tags: .desktop, paths

Trying to create a .desktop file for a program and it requires a universal username path so instead of `Exec=/home/john/myscript.sh` it's `Exec=/home/$USER/myscript.sh`.

in .desktop files you need an exact path and `$USER` does not work. Neither does `$LOGNAME`.

[.Desktop EXEC universal home path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736767/desktop-exec-universal-home-path)

^This did not work either (the edited solution not the one voted as). Because this solution did not work, it is not relevant to this question.

Not sure what else to try. If someone could chime in it'd help a lot. Thank you.

Here is my desktop file

`[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Exec=/bin/bash -c '/home/$USER/mycroft-core/start-mycroft.sh all'
Name=Mycroft AI
Icon=/usr/share/MycroftIcon/MycroftIcon.jpg
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

Edit: I had a typo in my code the solution provided by @mchild works:

The solution is: `Exec=/bin/bash -c '/home/$USER/myscript.sh'`

Comment: Why not put `myscript.sh` in the `/usr/local/bin` directory?

Comment: @waltinator it won't run from /usr/local/bin for some reason.

Comment: @vanadium I explicitly said in my initial post that the solution you posted (For some odd reason) did not work.

Comment: @mchid I have tried $HOME and it did not work

Comment: Are you sure there is not something else wrong with the desktop file? I tested the solution using `Exec=sh -c '$HOME/myscript.sh'` and `Exec=/bin/bash -c '/home/$USER/myscript.sh'` and it worked. Have you tested: `Exec=/home/john/myscript.sh` to see if that works? If it doesn't execute when you use the full path, you will  know that you have a different problem. I tested this on a desktop file in my Desktop directory. I had to right click on the file: > Properties > Permission > check the box for "allow executing as a program". Then, double-click the file on desktop and select to trust.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate of the other answer, please post the contents of your desktop file and also please verify that the desktop file will execute when you use the full path: `Exec=/home/john/myscript.sh` One problem could be that the `myscript.sh` file is not executable or you could have other lines in your file that are preventing the file from executing. Thanks!

Comment: @mchild desktop file added to original post. The script works fine as I have been using this desktop file for a while now without the $USER variable.

Comment: @mchild the script works fine if I replace `$USER` with my actual username

Comment: @mchild your solution worked, I had a typo in my code. Thanks so much!!